# Grails/AJAX: Updating an arbitrary region in the page using g:submitToRemote

Tags: ajax, grails, gsp

In a GSP (Groovy Server Page), I'm using `<g:submitToRemote update="...">` to update a `<div>` after the server-side call.

According to the tag's [documentation](http://www.grails.org/Tag+-+submitToRemote) and other sources on the web, the target `<div>` can be placed arbitrarily at the page. In my testings, however, I find that the `<div>` needs to surround the `<g:submitToRemote>` tag.

If it does *not*, the `<div>` will be updated with some "random" contents (i.e., *parts* of the form that surround the `<g:submitToRemote>` tag).

Consider the following GSP code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <g:javascript library="prototype" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="updateMe_NOT_WORKING">${message}</div>

<g:form>
    <div id="updateMe_WORKING">
        <g:submitToRemote value="Click Me"
            action="someAction" update="updateMe_NOT_WORKING" />
    </div>
</g:form>

</body>
</html>
```

That's on Grails 1.3.4.
What am I missing? - Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my testings, `g:submitToRemote`'s `action` attribute must *not* point to the *current controller's current action* (as this will insert/duplicate the current view *into* the current view).

It works if you specify an *alternate* action in `g:submitToRemote` - i.e.,

```
<g:submitToRemote value="Click Me"
    action="ajaxAction" update="updateMe" />
```

If this action provides a *model* - i.e.,

```
def ajaxAction = { [message: 'foo'] }
```

then there needs to be a corresponding GSP - that, in this case, should state,

```
$message
```

Alternatively, the action can use the `render` method - like this,

```
def ajaxAction = { render 'foo' }
```

---

*I'll leave this issue open for some time, in case there might be additional responses, and, if there aren't, will accept this answer as the solution.*

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you don't specify the controller for your action. Try adding controller="..." into your g:submitToRemote tag. Or at least specify it in g:form.

I'm sure that the `<div>` doesn't need to be wrapped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer [+]. - It caused me to look deeper into the issue. - The `controller` attribute doesn't actually make a difference, but it's the `action` attribute (which must reference an action that's not the *current* one, plus certain additional conditions being involved).

Comment: Yes, it's the common problem for developers who aren't familliar with MVC in Grails. I was in trouble with it for quite a time.